# Need help refining regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm having an issue with my regex matching a string which I do not want it to match.  I can't seem to find the correct syntax for the expression.  Here is an example:

#### String:

```
ABC098765432109,~~Z 10Y-123~This is a test^ABC-DE-_F
```

#### Regex:

```
m/^.\*?,\d\*[\~]{2}\w\s\d\*\w-\d\*~.\*?\^.\*?-.\*?-.\*?_\w$/
```

---

The `,\d*` portion I thought would eliminate the string which has no digits directly after the comma.

Any suggestions on getting this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"*"` means **"zero or more"**. You may want `"+"`, which means **"one or more"**. So,

```
m/^.*?,\d+[\~]{2}\w\s\d*\w-\d*~.*?\^.*?-.*?-.*?_\w$/
```

does not match

```
",~~Z 10Y-123~This is a test^ABC-DE-_F"
```

Answer (score 3):

`*` means "zero or more", so it will match no numbers as well.

Use `\d+` or `\d\d*` to match at least one digit